# Pull output down if either of multiple pins are pulled down

Tags: diodes, boolean-algebra, pulldown

(Sorry in case I used the wrong terminology, let me explain.)

### Context

I have a relay board I'm controlling. It has 8 relays, and 8 low level triggering pins for control.

7 of the relays I want to control separately from each other, while the 8th should trigger if any of the other 7 are triggered.

### Question

I know how to control a pin from HIGH to LOW. But how would I implement this "OR" logic in hardware? If it has triggering on HIGH, I would have put a diode between every pin and the 8th pin, that would have pulled it HIGH if any of the others were.

So I understand I could fix it in code, but I rather have something that is sensitive to corner cases.

Comment: "I would have put a zener diode between every pin and the 8th pin" why a zener? That seems like a strange choice.

Comment: true, is should be a regular diode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use standard diodes. 7 of them. If any pulls low, it will pull the 8th input low. Although if you have extra GPIO for that it might be simpler to do it in software.

Comment: Could you explain how that works? I can understand it working with pulling high, since then either one of the seven diodes will forward current. how does that work in reverse?

Comment: @DavyLandman: It will work the same a pulling up, but the diodes point the other way...